# SSRS Report Builder in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Report Builder in SSRS will not open in Chrome, but it will in IE.

Is there any special setup that needs to be done in order to open Report Builder from Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome is not a supported browser for SSRS Report Builder.  Only IE, Firefox and Safari are "officially" supported.  There have been some who have suggestions for possible workarounds, but I haven't tried any of these.

1. Update Reporting Services or Repair installation - might be corrupted
2. Check that Report Builder app actually exists where it is supposed to for ClickOnce install to work.
3. Try providing a link to access Report Builder directly: /ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder.application

More info can found at these links: [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/47c9f7c6-00ed-4980-9667-5c176ad7116a/ssrs-report-builder-application-cannot-be-started-contact-application-vendor), [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) & [TechNet Forums](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f50eb196-3f15-408d-acb7-7f90e3348e3e/why-does-the-ssrs-calendar-control-not-work-in-google-chrome-but-plenty-of-other-websites-with)

Comment: The third possible workaround worked for me.  I provided a link to the /ReportServer/ReportBuilder/ReportBuilder_3_0_0_0.application.

Answer (score 1):

Install [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) (or [similar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/internet%20explorer%20tab)) extension for Chrome. The extension uses the Internet Explorer engine to render pages in a Chrome tab.

It's also a good way to work around some of the CSS issues you'll see in Chrome with the Report Manager application.